# Service Fabric Actors, ReceiveReminderAsync and CancellationTokens

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, cancellationtokensource, service-fabric-actor

I have an Azure Service Fabric actor that uses reminders.

- What happens if I delete my service or upgrade it while the actor is in the middle of the `ReceiveReminderAsync` method?
- Can I send a cancellation token to the `ReceiveReminderAsync` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actors follow the [single entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-reentrancy) pattern by default.
While a reminder callback is being processed, no other operations (like Deactivate) can occur. Deletions (unless forced) and upgrades are delayed until the operation completes.

The receive reminder uses the [IRemindable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.runtime.iremindable.receivereminderasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Actors_Runtime_IRemindable_ReceiveReminderAsync_System_String_System_Byte___System_TimeSpan_System_TimeSpan_) interface. It has no cancellation support.

Comment: Can actor method support cancel token?  Then how do you request cancel from client to the actor?  I have not been successful in seeing actor register method hit breakpoints when token.Canel() is called from client.